# Cycles texture mapping, generated coordinates with world orientation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Basically I want to map a texture in cycles with the generated coordinates, but have it ignore the orientation of the object.

The effect I want to achieve is a material that has a gradient, spread top to bottom of the individual objects dimensions, but always orientated top to bottom of the world no-matter how the object is rotated.

Any way to achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 15):

Yes, this is possible.

There are several ways to achieve this, here are a couple:

### Position:

You can use the *Position* output of the *Geometry node* and separate out the blue (vertical) channel:

[image]

Note that since it's based on the world center some objects end up with values outside the 0-1 range:

[image]

### Texture Coordinate:

You can also use the *Object* or the *Generated* output of the *Texture coordinate* node and convert it to world space with the *Vector Transform* node:

[image]

Now each object will have a gradient from `1` at the top to `0` at the bottom regardless of rotation:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, almost, but it is not quite right, see the gradient is not spread all the way. Black should only be at the very bottom of the object.

Comment: Just add 1.0 to the gradient, and multiply by 0.5. That'll move it to the bottom and then spread it back up to reach the top

Comment: It's not taking into consideration the actual bounds of the mesh, this is a gradient around the origin of the object that spreads from 0 to 1 on the world Z axis starting from the object origin. For example just move the mesh in edit mode away from the object center.

Comment: @Rhys It's possible if you know the dimensions of the object, but the dimension data blender stores in `object.dimensions` is based on the origin, so even if you use a driver to get the Z dimension into the node editor you still need to center the origin.