# Gradient that depends on an absolute value (several objects)

Tags: node-editor

Let's assume I have a 10x10 array of columns of varying height. I have a node flow to equip them with a color gradient depending on their height. But is there any way to have an absolute reference, meaning that a height of 1 corresponds to white and then it goes towards black? Right now every column goes through the whole gradient, but the smaller ones should be only in the dark region. If something is unclear I am happy to clarify. Please see a render and the nodes below. [image: Render] [image].
Thank you,

Steffen

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7222/cycles-texture-mapping-generated-coordinates-with-world-orientation

Comment: Either use the *Vector Transform* node, or use *Object* texture coordinates, if your objects have applied scale values.

Comment: nice, the geometry+separate RGB node in the post mentioned by @MrZak  did it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the texture coordinates depend on another object, or an empty.

[image]

[image]