# Gradient shader according to the polygons size

Tags: node-editor, shaders

If I create a (very basic) gradient shader it's applied to the whole object the same way. Even if exists a different material for the small rectangle but same nodes I get the same result:

[image: Same gradient for the whole object]

But, is there an automatic way to copy that nodes to a new material (in this case the drawer) and get the gradient according to the size of the polygons similar to this image?

[image: I change the gradient for the drawer manually... is it possible automatically?]

I had to change the color ramp in the drawer material manually, but if the gradient could adapt to the size of the polygons it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Gradient that depends on an absoulut value for several objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90870/gradient-that-depends-on-an-absolute-value-several-objects) and [texture mapping generated coordinates with world orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7222/cycles-texture-mapping-generated-coordinates-with-world-orientation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using generated texture coordinates.  Generated texture coordinates are generated by looking at the bounding box of your object (before any deforming modifiers, but after any generative modifiers).  They range from 0 at the bottom, left, front of your object to +1 at the top, right, back of your object.  Because your drawer has a different bounding box, this means they are different coordinates.

You can revise your existing material to use different coordinates, although this is going to require some other editing.  Probably simplest is to make all objects from the material use the *object* coordinates of the larger cube.  However, object coordinates range from -1 to +1 instead of 0 to 1-- or at least, for your purposes they will-- and so you'll probably need to map them a bit:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Nathan. I didn't specify it's the same object so if I use "Generated" instead "Object" your node tree works for me. Thanks for your help. Anyway there is a simpler node tree I posted below from another post: The problem of another user is my solution XD  (thanks to StackExchange algorithm!)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of another user is also another answer for my problem (thanks, Stackexchange algorithm!) [Gradient that depends on an absolute value (several objects)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90870/gradient-that-depends-on-an-absolute-value-several-objects)